# Relationship between two tables in different schemas using spring boot jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, entity-relationship

I am working on a multi tenant application for school management. Each school has a common schema to store student details and staff details and a schema per academic year to store the academic year specific data. I want to reference the tables in the school's main schema from the tables in the academic year schemas  using spring boot jpa.

Here is an illustration.

[image]

There are many schools. How can I achieve this functionality ?

I searched a lot but could not find anything. I am using spring boot 1.5.9 with mysql 5.7

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion there should be multiple databases for each tenant would be best solution rather using same db for every tenant/client. You can define common schema but the database will be persisted in its own database. You can place Spring @Profile to your module/component to do specific thing for a particular tenant.

You can gone through below article for more detail.

https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-hibernate-multitenancy-implementation

Comment: I already have that implemented. I am able to login as different users with unique schema access. My requirement is that each user has multiple schemas: A main schema and sub ones. I want the tables in sub schemas to have relationship with the tables in the main schema

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Because two databases are independent each and you want to relate each other. I think you should think about design of database again.